# Is there a "When" type-thing?

Tags: c#, events

Is there anything that will wait for an event to happen (the one I'm waiting for is WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted), then execute code? Something like this:

> If (WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted)

won't work because it will just skip the code if it returns false.

Comment: You can create an awaiter for it (eg, using `TaskCompletionSource`) and use C# 5 `async`.

Comment: What sort of program are you writing?  The best answer will be different for WinForms, WPF, Console, etc.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin WinForms

Comment: USe Events to achieve this ..

Comment: Weak events if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered subscribing to the *WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted* event?

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    //process web page
};
//keep on processing asynchronously here... (if you want :-p)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to bind to the event:

```
WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

...

private WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Respond to the event
}
```

**Further Reading:**

- [Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement it seems to me there are two possibilities to work around the issue depending on the conditions:

> 1. Register `DocumentCompleted` event and use [WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event handler to deal with the stuff
>      you are planning to execute. The piece of code will *wait* till the
>      document does not load completely.
> 2. If your use `Timer` class for continuous polling, you should look at [WebBrowser.IsBusy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.isbusy.aspx) property. And if it is *false* the document
>      has been finished loading. But it will not be a good approach to use
>      `Timer` class if you have a facility of `DocumentCompleted` event. If
>      you use this approach change it.